# Freebase supermarkets/grocery stores/food shops

Tags: api, bigdata, freebase, opendata

I'm using Freebase API to get some geolocation. Is there any way to get all supermarkets/grocery stores/food shops from world map? 
I found out type:/base/services/grocery_store but it gives only 6 results. Is there some type that gives much bigger amount of records? 
What I'm looking for is something like [this](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=202600437167360422093.00049b023de1c4d95c219&msa=0&ll=41.899849,12.505875&spn=0.125214,0.264187).
May be there is some another API to get such data?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a domain where Freebase contains much data.  I'm guessing that information sources that you find are likely to be locale specific (ie you won't find a worldwide source).